# Tomcat welcome page - cannot access

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed tomcat7.x-x64 on WinServer2012.

On the WinServer2012 own, the Tomcat welcome page shows properly.

When I use my own computer, Windows XP, it can't access the page.

On WinServer2012 I have used a url like this:

`http://x.x.x.x:8080/`

This works OK.

On my computer I use a url like this:

`http://x.x.x.x:8080/`

An error occurs.

x.x.x.x -> the server's IP address

How can I visit the remote server(WinServer2012)'s Tomcat pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: When you access Tomcat's welcome page from the machine running the web server, it works.  When you try to access the same page from a different computer, it does not.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Are both computers on the same network?  Can you ping the host computer from the client computer?

Comment: Yes, I have pinged the server success when I have not closed the firewall... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Edward very likely your problem is related to firewall configuration. Either your WinServer2012 firewall does not allow connections to port 8080 OR if your two machines (server and desktop) are two different networks then there might be hardware-based firewall (router?) that may not be allowing incoming connections. I would check firewall configurations.

Comment: Agreed, most likely a firewall issue (software).  However, how sure are you the tomcat started up correctly?

Comment: @NeilA From his note that he could access it on a local machine (i.e. "This works OK."), I concluded that Tomcat fired up without any problems - at least for dishing out that welcome page. At that point, this is most likely (99.9%) related to firewall issue.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks very much, I have closed the server's firewall, but cannot ping this server success...

Comment: @Edward you said you "closed" firewall!!! I think its a communication gap here because you probably meant "opened" firewall port or something like that! Getting firewall configured is a fairly tricky situation depending on which firewall is blocking things, your network setup and more. I wouldn't recommend disabling firewall but just to test things out... you should try disabling it for a short period - try googling "windows server 2012 disable firewall" and you may find many references. I also recommend that you get help from someone who understands server admin/networking.

Comment: Thank you very much! smallworld.